# Laravel Backpack select_and_order: how to make options list dependent on model being edited

Tags: laravel-backpack

I have a select_and_order field that works in my

```
use App\Models\Tool;
class ProjectCrudController extends CrudController
{

protected function setupCreateOperation()
{
    CRUD::addField([
        'name' => 'tools'
        'type' => 'select_and_order',
        'options' => Tool::get()->pluck('selector','id'),
    ]);
```

Now the possible tools are dependent on the type of project, so instead of returning all tools to `options` as above, I would like something like

```
    CRUD::addField([
        'name' => 'tools'
        'type' => 'select_and_order',
        'options' => Tool
            ::projectTypeFilter($this->crud->model->type)
            ->pluck('selector','id'),
    ]);
```

But the new query returns `[]` because - as far as I can see - `$this->crud->model` is not hydrated.

```
protected function setupUpdateOperation()
{
    CRUD::addField([
        'name' => 'naam',
        'type' => 'select_and_order',
        'options' => dump($this->crud->getModel()),
    ]);
}
```

shows

```
App\Models\Project {#1779 ▼
    #guarded: array:1 [▶]
    #fakeColumns: array:1 [▶]
    #casts: array:4 [▶]
    #connection: null
    #table: null
    #primaryKey: "id"
    #keyType: "int"
    +incrementing: true
    #with: []
    #withCount: []
    +preventsLazyLoading: false
    #perPage: 15
    +exists: false
    +wasRecentlyCreated: false
    #escapeWhenCastingToString: false
    #attributes: []
    #original: []
    #changes: []
    #classCastCache: []
    #attributeCastCache: []
    #dates: []
    #dateFormat: null
    #appends: []
    #dispatchesEvents: []
    #observables: []
    #relations: []
    #touches: []
    +timestamps: true
    #hidden: []
    #visible: []
    #fillable: []
}
```

How can I have the model hydrated?

Comment: The model should be hydrated by that point. Does $this->crud->getModel() work?

Comment: @tabacitu, no the model is not hydrated, I tested that as now shown in the question.  How can I have it hydrated?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think what you're looking for is not `$this->crud->getModel()` (which will get you the Eloquent model class), but `$this->crud->getCurrentEntry()` which will get you:

- `false`, if the model has not been hydrate (eg. inside `setupCreateOperation()`, where there is no current entry to speak of);
- the current entry for that Eloquent model, if present (eg. inside `setupUpdateOperation()`;

Comment: great, thank for your support @tabacitu